# Erase a part of a std::string multiple times

Tags: c++

I have this string:

```
"WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"
```

And I want to delete `"WUB"` to be `"WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND"`. I tried this code
but it doesn't work, although it works with `"WUBWUBABCWUB"` and gives the correct output `"ABC"`.

```
int main()
{
    std::string x,s;
    std::cin >> x;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        s = x.erase(x.find("WUB"), 3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: *I tried this code but it doesn't work* What code? And how exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ string x,s;
cin>>x;
for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
{s=x.erase(x.find("WUB"),3);}
cout<<s;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Random Use edit feature to add it to the question. Also add actual output.

Comment: @Random How on earth do you think that code *would* work?! It doesn't even contain the replacement string (the space).

Comment: @Borgleader it does't work at all there is no output, there is message appear that " A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.Please close the program"

Comment: @Random, According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), passing an index greater than the size (like from `find` when nothing is found) throws an exception. It's a bit unfortunate if your environment does not report uncaught exceptions, as that would give a much clearer error message.

Comment: @Random The symptoms and the code should be in the question, not delivered piece by piece in comments.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am so sorry but  it is my first time and I don't know really how  to do it correctly

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/951eb84368bb2c55

Comment: Sorry to be the one, but code should not be an image, just text. I recommend reading [ask].

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are causing the issue?

Comment: @chris and here I tought it was the new SO syntax highlighter

Comment: @chris I should have noticed that when I approved the edit. I too thought it was some type of new syntax highlighter ..

Comment: @drescherjm, Nope, just CodeBlocks :)

Comment: Ten downvotes are too much. I'm gonna upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when all occurences of WUB are erased: if there is no WUB left in the string, find will return the magic value string::npos, which is usually a very large number and accessing this index will likely lead to an out of bounds exception.

[See the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

> The position of the first character of the first match. If no matches
>   were found, the function returns string::npos.

Here is a [working example in Ide-One](http://ideone.com/QZYWkB), without the new line below it will throw:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 4294967295) > this->size() (which is 25)
```

Adding a check if the string contains the search string fixes the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";
    string s;
    for(int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
    {
        if (x.find("WUB") != string::npos) // <=== this is new
            s = x.erase(x.find("WUB"),3);
    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I don't think the question deserved 10 downvotes.